# c++ value_type not work for std::tr1:tuple in a std::map

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, stdmap

The following code snippet work with Visual Studio 2008 but not with Visual Studio 2010.

```
template <typename TKey>
struct MyStruct
{
    typedef std::map<TKey, int>  Keys;

    MyStruct()
    {
    }

    void set(TKey& key)
    {
#if 1
        // This works with VS 2008 but not with 2010
        keys_.insert(typename Keys::value_type(key, 1));
#else
        // This works with VS 2008 and VS 2010
        keys_.insert(std::pair<TKey, int>(key, 1));
#endif
    };

private:
    Keys keys_;
};
```

Usage

```
typedef std::tr1::tuple<int, int> MyValueType;
MyStruct<MyValueType> a;
MyValueType x;
a.set(x);
```

I get following error:

> 1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\tuple(127):
>   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const MyValueType'
>   to 'int' 1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available
>   that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called 1> 
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxtuple0(9) :
>   see reference to function template instantiation
>   'std::tr1::_Cons_node<_Car,_Cdr>::_Cons_node<_Ty,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&>(_Farg0
>   &&,_Farg1,_Farg2,_Farg3,_Farg4,_Farg5,_Farg6,_Farg7,_Farg8,_Farg9)'
>   being compiled 1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   _Car=int, 1>              _Cdr=std::tr1::_Cons_node::_Type>,
>   1>              _Ty=MyValueType, 1>              _Farg0=MyValueType,
>   1>              _Farg1=std::tr1::_Nil &, 1>
>   _Farg2=std::tr1::_Nil &, 1>              _Farg3=std::tr1::_Nil &, 1>              _Farg4=std::tr1::_Nil &, 1>              _Farg5=std::tr1::_Nil &, 1>              _Farg6=std::tr1::_Nil &, 1>              _Farg7=std::tr1::_Nil &, 1>              _Farg8=std::tr1::_Nil &, 1>              _Farg9=std::tr1::_Nil & 1>          ] 1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\utility(145) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tr1::tuple<_Arg0,_Arg1>::tuple>(_Farg0 &&)' being compiled 1>
>   with 1>          [ 1>              _Arg0=int, 1>
>   _Arg1=int, 1>              _Farg0=const std::tr1::tuple 1>          ] 1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\utility(142) : while compiling class template member function 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::_Pair_base(const
>   std::tr1::tuple<_Arg0,_Arg1> &&,int &&)' 1>          with 1>
>   [ 1>              _Ty1=const MyValueType, 1>              _Ty2=int, 1>
>   _Arg0=int, 1>              _Arg1=int 1>          ] 1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\utility(174)
>   : see reference to class template instantiation
>   'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>' being compiled 1>          with 1>
>   [ 1>              _Ty1=const MyValueType, 1>              _Ty2=int 1> 
>   ] 1>
>   D:\Projekte\demo\Demo.cpp(40)
>   : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>'
>   being compiled 1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   _Ty1=const MyValueType, 1>              _Ty2=int 1>          ] 1>          D:\Projekte\demo\Demo.cpp(39)
>   : while compiling class template member function 'void
>   MyStruct::set(TKey &)' 1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   TKey=MyValueType 1>          ] 1>
>   D:\Projekte\demo\Demo.cpp(92)
>   : see reference to class template instantiation 'MyStruct' being
>   compiled 1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   TKey=MyValueType 1>          ] 1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 10.0\VC\include\tuple(127): error C2439:
>   'std::tr1::_Cons_node<_Car,_Cdr>::_Value' : member could not be
>   initialized 1>          with 1>          [ 1>              _Car=int,
>   1>
>   _Cdr=std::tr1::_Cons_node::_Type>
>   1>          ] 1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\tuple(170) : see declaration of 'std::tr1::_Cons_node<_Car,_Cdr>::_Value' 1>          with 1>
>   [ 1>              _Car=int, 1>
>   _Cdr=std::tr1::_Cons_node::_Type>
>   1>          ]
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

If a replace typedef std::tr1::tuple MyValueType with typedef int MyValueType it works.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems to be a compiler bug, it [compiles on gcc](http://liveworkspace.org/code/a21f9394d98fef376487a2e9ce1fc868). You are missing `typename` before `Keys::value_type` (since `value_type` depends on `TKey`); but adding that doesn't fix the error either.

Comment: Usually, I use `keys_.insert(std::make_pair(key, 1));` for such inserts. This should always work.

Comment: Oh, yes I forgot the typename. I extracted MyStruct from I third-party library that I used in my project. There has the typename. So I fix the sample above.

Comment: The problem lies with `value_type` being `pair<K const, V>` and it seems MSVC's implementation of `pair` doesn't correctly move from `const` qualified members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an error that related to bad implementation of move semantic in MSVC 2010 since you can successfully compile this code:

```
typename Keys::value_type v( key, 1 );
keys_.insert(v);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses.
Is there a other way to compile the code without changing MyStruct.
Because I extracted MyStruct from a third-party library (Poco) that I used in my project.